# JSON.NET Serialize as Parent Type

Tags: c#, json, types, json.net, polymorphism

I am working on a project where I would like to save the state of an object using human-readable JSON. However, I am running into issues when the originating object of serialization is not the base class. As an example, here is a class and base class:

```
public class TeaPot 
{
    public TeaPot() 
        => Console.WriteLine("I want this.");
}

public sealed class TeaPotFactory : TeaPot 
{
    public TeaPotFactory() 
        : base()
        => Console.WriteLine("I do not want this!");
}

TeaPot greenTea = new TeaPotFactory();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(greenTea);
```

The string `json` will then contain the following content:

```
    {
        "$type": "Project.Factories.TeaPotFactory, TeaShop",
        "Name": "Green Tea",
        "Price": 5.99,
    }
```

This means when the JSON is deserialized the factory constructor will run again causing unintended side-effects. Example console output:

```
# I want this.
# I do not want this!
```

This happens even if I specify the deserialization type as the base class (`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TeaPot>`).

I need and have purposefully turned on explicit types for the JSON output as there are types that come from the same base implementation.

How can I get Newtonsoft.Json (JSON.NET) to define the type of the object as its base class? I know with Newtonsoft you can define your own converter, but this would not be an optimal solution as it adds yet another class and a lot of boilerplate code.

The original code for serialization and deserialization was requested:

```
[Singleton]
public static class Serializer
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
    };
}

public class Bundle {/* ... */}

public class BundleFactory : Bundle {/* ... */}

public sealed class BundleCollection : ISerializable
{
    public Bundle[] Bundles 
    { get; set; }

    public override string Serialize()
    => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Serializer.Settings);
}
```

Here is a segment of the output when I output BundleCollection:

```
{
  "Bundles": [
    {
      "$type": "Integration.Factories.BundleFactory, IntegrationService",
      "Name": "FisherScientific",
      "Transporters": [
        {
          "$type": "Integration.Transport.LocalSftp, IntegrationProvider",
          "Directory": "~/Fisher/"
        }
      ],
      "Parsers": [
        {
          "$type": "Integration.Parse.Excel, IntegrationProvider",
          "Mapping": {
            "Customer": "A",
            "Item": "I",
            "Quantity": "D",
            "TrackingNo": "N"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify: is there a relationship between your class of `TeaPot` and `TeaPotFactory`?

Comment: @Saar my bad... updated the post as well to reflect this. TeaPotFactory is a child of TeaPot which simply implements a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Using Newtonsoft.Json, everything by default, I don't see the problem you stating. Here's the code I use for testing:

```cs
TeaPot greenTea = new TeaPotFactory();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(greenTea);

Console.WriteLine("Deserialization:");
TeaPot parent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TeaPot>(json);
```

Here's the output:

> I want this.
> I do not want this!
> Deserialization:
> I want this.

Line 1 and 2 is called because you are calling `new TeaFactory()`, which will always construct parent class before construct derived - that is normal.

Line 3 is a marker before deserialization.

Line 4 is called during the deserialization. And I don't see `I do not want this!`  being called.

Does that match what you want?

Comment: For some reason, mine keeps setting the type to the factory. I have to use 12.0.3 because of the legacy code, could they have fixed this in a later version? My settings are { TypeNameHandling.Objects, NullValueHandling.Include }

Comment: Tried on 12.0.3 with the settings. Still not getting the repro. Could you please share the code for deserialization?

Comment: I added the original code to the question, hope this helps...